# How to find all satisfying valuations for an infinite set of formulas

Tags: propositional-calculus, formal-languages

Im trying to find all satisfying valuations for an infinite set of formulas

$$M = \{A_1 \lor A_2, ¬A_2 \lor ¬A_3, A_3 \lor A_4, ¬A_4 \lor ¬A_5, A_5 \lor A_6, \dots\}$$
I cant really imagine myself solving this with my knowledge about sets in infinity so I would like to get a tip or two.

Comment: As a general rule, finding out even **if** a **finite** set of formulae are satisfiable is hard. But if they are of this form, where each term is of the form $P_n\lor Q_{n}$ where each $P_{n}$ is either $A_n$ or $\lnot A_n$ and $Q_n$ is one of $A_{n+1}$ or $\lnot A_{n+1},$ then we can certainly define all values inductively, although there will be uncountably many possible such sequences.

Comment: There is a famous computational problem, **3-SAT,** which is NP-complete, which asks for whether a finite set of $n$ statements of the form $A\lor B\lor C$ where $A,B,C$ are all either variables or. $\lnot$ of a variable, is the set satisfiable. That question, as far as we know, requires exponential time in $n.$ For an infinite set to be satisfiable, you will at least need each finite subset to be satisfiable. So a 'method' or 'algorithm' for solving this general question is very tricky, even if $M$ is recursively enumerable. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boolean_satisfiability_problem

Answer (score 2):

I'll assume this pattern continues, with $A_{2i-1} \vee A_{2i}$  and $\neg A_{2i} \vee \neg A_{2i+1}$ for all $i \ge 1$.

If any odd-numbered variable is false or any even-numbered one is true, then the sequence must alternate from that point on, with even-numbered variables true and odd ones false. On the other hand, if any odd-numbered variable is true or any even-numbered one is false, the sequence up to that point must alternate, with odd-numbered variables true and even-numbered ones false.  So either the whole sequence is alternating $(F,T,F,\ldots)$ or $(T,F,T,\ldots)$, or there is one point where it switches:
$(T,F,T,\ldots,F,F,T,F,T,\ldots)$ or $(T,F,T,\ldots,T,T,F,T,F,\ldots)$.